# Add labels to panel on button click

Tags: java, grid, nullpointerexception, awt, label

I have this code in Java in a button event, I add labels in a panel, the problem is that when i try to access a property like the X location of an element of my array of JLabels it gives me a `NullPointerException`, but when I do it in another button after I add the labels it works!

How can I get the x location of mi label in when pressing the button?

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    gridLabels=new JLabel[8];
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,8));
    for (int i = 0; i <  7; i++) 
    {
       gridLabels[i]=new JLabel(); 
       panel.add(gridCartasJ1[i]);
     }
int X = gridLabels[7].getX(); //<---Error
```

Comment: You state "Error" but don't give the error message. Please post this as well.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Always copy/paste error & exception output. .

Answer (score 2):

You're using "magic" numbers, and should avoid doing this, but more importantly, you should understand that arrays in Java are 0 based, meaning an array of 8 items goes from item 0 to item 7. You're trying to get an item beyond the array limit.

So rather than

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    gridLabels=new JLabel[8];
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,8));
    for (int i = 0; i <  7; i++) 
    {
       gridLabels[i]=new JLabel(); 
       panel.add(gridCartasJ1[i]);
    }
```

Do:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    gridLabels=new JLabel[8];
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,8));
    for (int i = 0; i <  gridLabels.length; i++) 
    {
       gridLabels[i]=new JLabel(); 
       panel.add(gridCartasJ1[i]);
    }
```

And don't try to use an array item that is equal to or beyond the length value since you'll cause an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception.

Answer (score 0):

well yes...

You initialize gridLabels[0] through gridLabels[6]

```
for (int i = 0; i <  7; i++)
```

and then you address gridLabels[7]

```
int X = gridLabels[7].getX();
```

You probably want

```
for (int i = 0; i <=  7; i++)
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i <  8; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are exceeding the limit of gridLabels array. You are filling the array 0 to 6, not 7.